# wget not saving file after download

Tags: wget, powershell

So I am currently using the `wget` command on windows 10 powershell to download various files. However, when testing this command, files do not actually download.

For example, say I want to download an image, say https://picsum.photos/200, I would use the following command:

`PS C:\Users\myname\Desktop> wget https://picsum.photos/200`

Which returns an apparently successful result:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {255, 216, 255, 224...}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length
                Content-Disposition: inline;filename=""
                Vary: Origin
                Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
                X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
                X-XSS-Protection...
Headers           : {[Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Content-Length], [Content-Disposition, inline;filename=""],
                [Vary, Origin], [Access-Control-Allow-Origin, *]...}
RawContentLength  : 31273
```

Once this process finishes, I do not observe any new files on my desktop.

However, this code does work:

```
wget https://picsum.photos/200 -O image.jpg
```

So what is going on? Why does `wget` alone not download the file?

Comment: Your command looks fine. Where did this implementation of `wget ` come from?

Comment: powershell uses `wget` and `curl` as aliases for its own [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Invoke-WebRequest).  It's not clear to me that there is any relationship to `wget` other than capturing the typing habits of users of other operating systems.

Comment: Mmm (it's nice to learn something else new). Arguably though, this is off-topic because we're talking about a Powershell command, not a UNIX/Linux utility.

Comment: @TimothyMartin initially that was my perspective too, but then I thought that it might be worth leaving open so that we can highlight that `wget` isn't `wget`. (IYSWIM.)

Comment: @roaima Good point.  I'll retract my vote to close.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Powershell implementation of `wget` is not `wget`. So it doesn't behave like the UNIX/Linux utility `wget`.

As [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359972/wget-not-saving-file-after-download/359977#comment637344_359972)  by user4556274, Powershell uses `wget` and `curl` as aliases for its own [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Invoke-WebRequest).

Looking at that (or running `Get-Help wget` under Powershell) it can be seen that the `-O [filename]` flag is an acceptable abbreviation for `-Output [filename]`, and that `Invoke-WebRequest [URI]` actually returns an object representing a web page rather than writing a file named from the basename of the URL.

Thus, this returns "nothing" unless you assign it to a variable or pipe it to another command:

```
wget http://example.net/path/to/page.html
```

But this delivers a web page "as expected":

```
wget http://example.net/path/to/page.html -O page.html
```

Comment: Makes sense. That is kind of silly that Powershell would use a command that doesn't do what it is commonly known for in UNIX

Comment: It has an alias (pardon me - `Alias`) that basically "fakes" it.  See also `ls` which IIRC is an Alias for `Get-ChildItem` (with certain parameters).

Comment: Powershell gonna powershell.